# What are proper names of delegate-enclosing classes?

Tags: java, delegates, naming-conventions

I have a following abstract class.

```
abstract class AbstractSome implements Interface1, Interface2 {
    // all methods defined in Interface1 is implemented
}
```

Now I want to extend this class using a delegate implementing `Interface2`.

```
class ????Some extends AbstractSome {

    public ????Some(final Interface2 delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override // defined in Interface2
    public void doSomething() {
        delegate.doSomething();
    }

    private final Interface2 delegate;
}
```

Is there any good `naming-convention` for this enclosing class?

Is `Delegating...` or `Default...` good?

Comment: This seems to be opinion based question, but I would like to see some good responses to it.

Comment: there is no such a convention. for classes abstract class InMemoryFile implements Readable, Writable i would call such class DelegateWriteInMemoryFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design you are using is so close to an [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), so I think it would be a good approach to use for class name something like `SomeAdapdter` or `SomeDelegateAdapter`

I think there are not a name convention for this particular situation

Answer (score 3):

I have stuck with the same question and have come to the conclusion that **Delegator** fits the best:

From [CollinsDictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/delegator):

*delegator* -- a person who delegates

Comment: Also some people indeed use a `Delegating` prefix.